# animation functions JQuery

Tags: jquery, slider

I am really breaking my head over this. I have the following code:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bannerTest.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="banner" id="box">

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#box").animate({height: "300px"});
                $("#box").animate({width: "100%"});
            }, 100); 
        });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.banner {
background:#98bf21;
height:100px;
width:100px;
margin:6px;
}
```

Alright, so when the page has loaded the script slide down vertically, and afterwords horizontally. This is inside a div tag.

[image: This looks like this:]

So if I now wanted a blue square that also slide down, how should I make this?

[image: What I would like:]

I was thinking I could make a new div, but that of course didn't work. I tried to make something like this, but I also need to style the "leftbox", but there is something wrong I guess. Something i misunderstand.

```
<div class="banner" id="box" id="leftbox">

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#box").animate({height: "300px"});
            $("#box").animate({width: "100%"});
            $("#leftbox").animate({width: "10%"});
        }, 100); // the 1000 is the delay in milliseconds
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Hope someone can help me?

Best Regards
Mads

EDITED CODE:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bannerTest.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-blue">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $(".banner").animate({height: "300px"}, 1000);
            $(".banner").animate({width: "100%"}, 1000);

                $(".banner-blue").animate({height: "300px"}, 1000);

            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    background:#98bf21;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin:6px;
}

.banner-blue {
    background:#0000ff;
    position:absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the green box to expand vertically and horizontally and the blue to expand horizontally.

Here is a working JSFiddle which contains a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/ruLtkc40/1/

In your code you have the following:

```
<div class="banner" id="box" id="leftbox">
```

Two things about ID's:

- You can only have one per element
- ID's need to be unique, so you can't have two elements with the ID of `box`

In the JSFiddle I've also used classes in the selectors instead of ID's as it keeps your elements tidy and you don't need to declare both an ID *and* a class.

I'd also recommend you put all your  tags at the top of the page instead of inside elements to keep your page organized.

Let me know if this is what you were trying to achieve.

**UPDATE**

I've placed the `banner-blue` animation in a callback, meaning it will only start after the `banner` animation has finished:

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
        $(".banner").animate({height: "300px"}, 1000);
        $(".banner").animate({width: "100%"}, 1000, function()
           {
            $(".banner-blue").animate({height: "300px"}, 1000);
           });

        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Frayt, that was exactly what I wanted. The only thing is that i wanted to get the blue square to go from top to down.

Comment: In that case just change `.banner-blue`'s css to `width: [your width]`, remove the `height: 100px` line, and change the animation from `width` to `height`

Comment: One thing is actually a little bit weird. When I take it over in my program, the blue load first and then the green afterwords.

Comment: Could you add your current javascript code onto the end of your post please so I can see what's happening?

Comment: I have added the code now. By the way, I didn't put the code in the head yet :-/

Comment: Updated my answer, should be fixed.